# Android - Twitter API - Bad Authentication for statuses/retweets

Tags: authentication, twitter

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of retweets of a tweet given its ID. Here is my request:

```
TwitterClient client = new TwitterClient(twitterSession);
    client.getRetweetsService().list(Long.parseLong(objectID), new Callback<Response>() { ... etc ... }
```

As you can see, I use a twitter session therefore the request is authenticated. And here is my interface:

```
interface Retweets {
@GET("/1.1/statuses/retweets/{id}.json")
void list(@Path("id") long objectID, Callback<Response> cb);
```

Which produces the following URL, just like the example twitter use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/509457288717819904.json
```

However I recieve the following (and the same if I use twitters example link)

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Can anybody help me? On this website it gives you a way to retrieve retweets

https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twittercore/1.3.4/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/services/StatusesService.html#retweet%28java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Boolean,%20com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback%29

"Returns a collection of the 100 most recent retweets of the tweet specified by the id parameter." but it's actually a POST and instead just retweets the tweet.